# $H^4$ of the Monster

Tags: monster, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras, group-cohomology

The Monster group $M$ acts on the moonshine vertex algebra $V^\natural$.

Because $V^\natural$ is a holomorphic vertex algebra (i.e., it has a unique irreducible module), there is a corresponding cohomology class $c\in H^3(M;S^1)=H^4(M;\mathbb Z)$
associated to this action.

> Roughly speaking, the construction of that class goes as follows:
>
> - For every $g\in M$, pick an irreducible twisted module $V_g$ (there is only one up to isomorphism).
> - For every pair $g,h\in M$, pick an isomorphism $V_g\boxtimes V_h \to V_{gh}$,
> - where $\boxtimes$ denotes the fusion of twisted reps.
> - Given three elements $g,h,k\in M$, the cocycle $c(g,h,k)\in S^1$ is the discrepancy between
>     $$
>   (V_g\boxtimes V_h)\boxtimes V_k \to V_{gh}\boxtimes V_k \to V_{ghk}\qquad\text{and}\qquad
>   V_g\boxtimes (V_h\boxtimes V_k) \to V_g\boxtimes V_{hk} \to V_{ghk}
>   $$

I think that not much known about $H^4(M,\mathbb Z)$. But is anything maybe known about that cohomology class? Is it non-zero? Assuming it is non-zero, would that have any implications?

More importantly: what is the *meaning* of that class?

Comment: Clearly, it's some sort of associator for the 2-gerbe sitting over the delooping of $M$.... ;-) but I reckon you'd have guessed this yourself. Breen's 1994 Asterisque volume may be useful here.

Comment: BTW, very nice question :)

Comment: Has there been recent progress on this question?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd As of today, I don't think anything publicly available has changed.  Naturally, it is a topic of active interest.

Comment: @S.Carnahan great. I ask because I believe I have made some progress on the question, but don't want to reproduce work that has already been done that I missed

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Well, there is semi-public information: Miyamoto announced at a conference last year that he has a proof that the Monster-fixed-point subVOA of $V^\natural$ is $C_2$-cofinite and rational.  This more or less implies the conditional arguments in my answer are valid.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I might be misremembering --- I can no longer find the video --- but I thought I saw an old MSRI lecture of yours in which you announced a similar result?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Perhaps you were watching the 57th minute of my talk here: http://www.birs.ca/events/2016/5-day-workshops/16w5009/videos

Comment: Ah, that's why I couldn't find it on msri's website.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is some evidence from characters that $H^4(M,\mathbb{Z})$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.  In particular, the conjugacy class 24J (made from certain elements of order 24) has a character of level 288, and the corresponding irreducible twisted modules have a character whose expansion is in powers of $q^{1/288}$.  Fusion in a cyclic group generated by a 24J element then yields a $1/12$ discrepancy in $L_0$-eigenvalues, meaning you will pick up 12th roots of unity from the associator.  If you pull back along a pointed map $B(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}) \to BM$ corresponding to an element in class 24J (i.e., if you forget about twisted modules outside this cyclic group) you get a cocycle of order 12.  This is the largest order you can get by this method - everything else divides 12.  I don't know how the cocycles corresponding to different cyclic groups fit together.

I don't know if you've seen Mason's paper, [Orbifold conformal field theory and cohomology of the monster](http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/NST/Mason.pdf), but it is about related stuff.  I don't understand how he got his meta-theorem with the number 48 at the end, though.

As far as implications or meaning of the cocycle, all I can say is that the automorphism 2-group of the category of twisted modules of $V^\natural$ has the monster as its truncation, and its 2-group structure is nontrivial.  I've heard some speculation about twisting monster-equivariant elliptic cohomology, but I don't understand it.  If you believe in AdS/CFT, this might say something about pure quantum gravity in 3 dimensions, but I have no idea what that would be.

**Update Nov 2, 2011:** I was at a conference in September, where G. Mason pointed out to me that $H^4(M,\mathbb{Z})$ probably contains an element of order 8, and therefore also $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$.  I believe the argument was the following: there is an order 8 element $g$ whose centralizer in the monster acts projectively on the unique irreducible $g$-twisted module of the monster vertex algebra $V^\natural$, such that one needs to pass to a cyclic degree 8 central extension to get an honest action.  Rather than just looking at $L_0$-eigenvalues, one needs to examine character tables to eliminate smaller central extensions here.  Naturally, like the claims I described before, the validity of this argument depends on some standard conjectures about the structure of twisted modules.

It seems that the relevant group-theoretic computation may have been known to S. Norton for quite some time.  In his 2001 paper *[From moonshine to the monster](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=GYmU_9EKQCEC&lpg=PA163&pg=PA163#v=onepage)* that reconstructed information about the monster from a revised form of the generalized moonshine conjecture, he explicitly included a 24th root-of-unity trace ambiguity.  I had thought perhaps he just liked the number 24 more than 12, but now I am leaning toward the possibility that he had a good reason.

Comment: "I've heard some speculation about twisting monster-equivariant elliptic cohomology, but I don't understand it": from whom?

Comment: from Jacob and Nora, but their stories seem to differ.

Comment: @Scott, you probably know this.  What is the maximal subgroup of the monster such that the orbifold of the moonshine still contains the $L(1/2,0)^{\oplus 48}$ frame?

Comment: @MarcelBischoff In theory the answer can be extracted from http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9707008 but it is probably easier if you just ask Robert Griess (at Michigan).  I think "what is the pointwise stabilizer of $L(1/2,0)^{\otimes 48}$ in the monster VOA?" is a slightly clearer version of your question.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I ask is because for this subgroup I in principle know how to find the cohomology class, I did not try yet, though.

Comment: What means   "the conjugacy class 24J (made from certain elements of order 24) has a character of level 288, and the corresponding irreducible twisted modules have a character whose expansion is in powers of q..." ? Map from Conjugacy class to irreps ? as i want here :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271067/monstrous-langlands-mckay-or-what-is-bijection-between-conjugacy-classes-and-irr   ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov It does not mean what you seem to want.  Level $N$ refers to the McKay-Thompson series, which is a modular function invariant under some $\Gamma_0(N)$.

Answer (score 26):

In [arXiv:1707.08388](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08388), I calculate that the cohomology class you described has order 24 and that it is not a characteristic class in the ordinary sense.

Comment: WOW. Could this help with [Witten's question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/248186/41291)?

Comment: This is a very nice result, but one may need some more work to justify the claim that [Bis12] allows the orbifold results of [ALY17] to transfer to the conformal net setting.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think Witten may have answered his own questions in https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06728

Comment: @S.Carnahan Thanks for the comment! I was too quick there (in part because I learned the argument from talking with Marcel, and thought it was explicit in [Bis12] but it is not). The missing sentence is that V_Leech and V^\natural are both strongly local, and hence so is their common index-p subalgebra.

Comment: There is a new version https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.031048/